# Adding punctuation to jquery results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to find all checked items in an HTML form and return a sentence including the checked items.  I have the sentence structure down, but am having a mental block figuring out how to append punctuation to the sentence, such as: "You have chosen "item1", Item2", and "Item3". Please click each link to learn more."

How can I add the comma between each item, and add an "and" before only the last one?

I've included a small snipped of my JQuery, if I need to show more I can.  Thanks!

```
$("#list").append("You have indicated an interest in ");
    $.each(linkValues, function(i, val) {
      $("#list").append("<a href='" + linkURL[i] + "'>" + val + "</a>   ");
    });
    $("#list").append("Please click on the links to learn more about these resources.");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a comma is easy:

```
$.each(linkValues, function(i, val) {
  $("#list").append("<a href='" + linkURL[i] + "'>" + val + "</a>,   ");
//                                                              ^^^
});
```

Getting it not to show up after the last one is a bit harder.

You can detect if it's the last one by checking `i` and `linkValues.length`:

```
i == linkValues.length - 1
```

Then, we can use the ternary operator to only add things when it's the last one:

```
$.each(linkValues, function(i, val) {
  var isLast = i == linkValues.length - 1;
  $("#list").append((isLast ? "and " : "") + "<a href='" + linkURL[i] + "'>" + val + "</a>" + (isLast ? ", " : " "));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly.  The only thing I changed was the  (isLast ? ", " : " ")); to be  (isLast ? ". " : ", ")); and it was spot on.  Thanks again!